# Instead of "for" in label what can i use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was working to create a toggle button in React.js,

i was creating input tag's dynamically,

so when i am going to apply for attribute in label it is not working.

please help me out with any other attribute in JS

```
render: function() {
    var checks = this.state.data.map(function(d) {
        return (
            <div className="switch">
                {d.id}
                <input id="toggle-1" className="toggle toggle-round" type="checkbox" checked={d.selected} onChange={this.__changeSelection.bind(this, d.id)} />
                <label for="toggle-1"></label>
            </div>
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/2822d63df2787f7571cf962db279a77feee85bb3/src/browser/ui/dom/HTMLDOMPropertyConfig.js#L166-170) it seems that, like `class` (where you need to use `className` instead) you need to use an alternate name - in this case `htmlFor`:

```
<label htmlFor="toggle-1"></label>
```

This *may* be because:

- [both `class` and `for` are reserved keywords in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords)
- The attribute name does not map one-to-one with the name exposed to JavaScript in these few cases and React chooses to match the JavaScript API, rather than importing the DOM one (React handles `data-*` and `aria-*` transformations, but the docs call that behavior out explicitly).